# Solving horizontal asymptote with $e^x$ in the equation

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to work on an equation which is

$$f(x) =\frac{2 + e^x}{ 5 + 3e^x}.$$

I am trying to solve for $f(x)$ as it approaches infinity from the left and right. I have seen the technique where one would use the highest power in the denominator and divide all elements of the equation by this but this time I am stuck. I don't see a variable with a power to divide everything by.

I have searched online for a tutorial but couldn't see anything that dealt with $e^x$ in terms of this kind of problem.

Does anyone know of any resources or have any suggestion on how to approach this.
Thanks

Comment: What is your equation? There's no equality sign in your expression.

Comment: @HowDoIMath He probably thought to find asymptotes of  f(x) = (2 + e^x) / 5 + 3(e^x)) as x goes to +/- infty.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just trying to find the asymptote, you don't actually have to solve it -- just imagine that $x$ is very large. Then what happens? When $x$ is very large, $e^x$ is even larger. Comparatively, the $2$ and $5$ in the numerator and denominator don't matter because, for example, $e^x \approx 2 * 10^{434}$ when $x=1000$. And $2 + 10^{434} \approx 10^{434}$. (The point is that as $x$ tends to infinity, the $e^x$ terms become so large that we can ignore the small constants being added to them.)

Your equation:
$$f(x) = \frac{2+e^x}{5+3e^x} \rightarrow \frac{e^x}{3e^x}$$

And if you cancel the $e^x$ in the fraction, you can see that the horizontal asymptote of this is just $f(x) = \frac 1 3$.

---

Above, we handled the case when $x \to +\infty$. We also have to handle the case in which $x \to -\infty$. When you have extremely small $x$, $e^x \approx 0$, so then you get:
$$f(x) = \frac{2+e^x}{5+3e^x} \to \frac{2+0}{5+3\cdot 0} = \frac 2 5$$
So $f(x) = \frac 2 5$ is the other asmyptote.

Comment: And do the same when $x$ is infinitely large but negative.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes -- I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

May be, you could change the problem to go back to situations you already faced. Let us rewrite $$f(x)=\frac{2+u}{5+u}$$ where $u=e^x$.

When $x$ is positive and very large, $u$ is very large; so you look for $$\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{2+u}{5+3u}$$ When $x$ is negative and very large, $u$ is very small; so you look for $$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{2+u}{5+3u}$$ You know how to solve these limits.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have not yet learned L'Hopital, for else this would have been easy.

$f(x)=\frac{2+e^x}{5+3e^x}$

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2+e^x}{5+3e^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{e^x}\cdot\frac{\frac{2}{e^x}+1}{\frac{5}{e^x}+3}=\lim_{x\to\infty}1\cdot\frac{0+1}{0+3}=\frac{1}{3}$

What we did here is divide by $e^x$ and note that $\frac{c}{e^x}$ approaches $0$ as $x$ approaches infinity where $c$ is any constant.

Also, you should take a look at L'hopital's rule.

As for $x\to-\infty$, $e^x$ goes to $0$ so all you have to do is plug in the values to get $\frac{2}{5}$

Comment: I had thought of L'Hopital but thought I couldn't use it here because I didn't have 0/0 or infinity/infinity.

Comment: Why doesn't it? As $x\to\infty$, $e^x\to\infty$ so you'd get $\frac{2+\infty}{5+3\infty}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Comment: What is the idea behind dividing by e^x ?  How did you know to do that ? I see how it works but am unsure of where it has come from

Comment: I thought I had to have infinity over infinity straight away . I still get confused when to use L'hopital and when to divide by the highest power in the denominator...and not I am unsure when to divide by e^x

Comment: The idea follows from the same idea for rational functions. There, we divide by the strongest powers so that all lower powers would tend to 0. Here, $e^x$ is the fastest-growing function (constants don't grow to $\infty$), so dividing by it we'd get those terms to go to $0$, and then be left with the fastest growing functions to deal with (since the others will be so slow, they won't even matter as $x\to\infty$.) Same idea as Newb's really.

Comment: @user3754366, what do you mean with having infinity/infinity straight away? If the numerator tends to infinity and the denominator tends to infinity, then that's what we call "infinity/infinity".

Comment: I meant without any constants in the equation

Comment: Oh, no, it doesn't matter., All that matters is that it tends to infinity.